# Correct JSON response for Retrofit+GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, gson

I have below response for one of my web service and I'm using Retrofit and GSON.

```
    {
    "error": false,
    "Timeline": {
        "Date": "2040-06-15",
        "bandList": {
            "breakfast": {
                "dosageList": {
                    "01": {
                        "packed": "true",
                        "medicineList": [
                            {
                                "medicine": {
                                    "id": "01",
                                    "name": "glipizide 5 mg tablet, 100 ",
                                    "category": "regular",
                                    "image": null,
                                    "indication": "NIDDM",
                                    "packed": true,
                                    "med_id": "352",
                                    "dosage": 1
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "medicine": {
                                    "id": "04",
                                    "name": "Frusemide (Terry White Chemists) 20 mg uncoated tablet, 100 ",
                                    "category": "regular",
                                    "image": null,
                                    "indication": "Fluid",
                                    "packed": true,
                                    "med_id": "4",
                                    "dosage": 2
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "02": {
                        "packed": "false",
                        "medicineList": [
                            {
                                "medicine": {
                                    "id": "05",
                                    "name": "Refresh Tears Plus 0.5% eye drops solution, 15 mL ",
                                    "category": "regular",
                                    "image": null,
                                    "indication": "Dry Eyes",
                                    "packed": false,
                                    "med_id": "372",
                                    "dosage": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Q1.
Is there a way to parse above response using model classes (POJOs) or without them? I'm stuck at generating model classes for above structure. How do I generate POJOs for above JSON?

Q2. I'm in a position how to convince to send below response, what is the correct structure/format for JSON? Is there any JSON standard I could show to the web developer to get this JSON format? (note:I'm okay to parse this structure)

```
{
"error": false,
"Timeline": {
    "Date": "2040-06-15",
    "band": [
        {
            "name": "breakfast",
            "dosage": [
                {
                    "id": "01",
                    "packed": "true",
                    "medicine": [
                        {
                            "id": "01",
                            "name": "glipizide 5 mg tablet, 100 ",
                            "category": "regular",
                            "image": null,
                            "indication": "NIDDM",
                            "packed": true,
                            "med_id": "52",
                            "dosage": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "04",
                            "name": "Frusemide (Terry White Chemists) 20 mg uncoated tablet, 100 ",
                            "category": "regular",
                            "image": null,
                            "indication": "Fluid",
                            "packed": true,
                            "med_id": "54",
                            "dosage": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "02",
                    "packed": "false",
                    "medicine": [
                        {
                            "id": "05",
                            "name": "Refresh Tears Plus 0.5% eye drops solution, 15 mL ",
                            "category": "regular",
                            "image": null,
                            "indication": "Dry Eyes",
                            "packed": false,
                            "med_id": "372",
                            "dosage": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I use to autogenerate POJOs using those sites, but its giving below responses for some classes. How do I convert this to proper class?

```
package ;
public class DosageList
{
    private 01 01;

    private 02 02;

    public void set01(01 01){
        this.01 = 01;
    }
    public 01 get01(){
        return this.01;
    }
    public void set02(02 02){
        this.02 = 02;
    }
    public 02 get02(){
        return this.02;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have almost done parsing first JSON, but stuck in here.

```
for (String bandName: event.getTimeline().getBand().keySet()) {

  Log.d("<<<--Band-->>>", "Value " + event.getTimeline().getBand().get(bandName));
  Band band = event.getTimeline().getBand().get(bandName);
  for (String dosageName:band.getDosage().keySet()) {
     Dosage dosage = band.getDosage().get(dosageName);
     Log.d("<<<--Dosage-->>>", "Value " + dosage.getMedicine());
          for (Medicine medicine: dosage.getMedicine()) {
               Log.d("<<<--Medicine-->>>", "Value " + dosage.getMedicine().get(0));
          }
   }

}
```

How do I retrieve medicine values?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Medicine
     {
    private String id;

private String name;

private String category;

private String image;

private String indication;

private boolean packed;

private String med_id;

private int dosage;

public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
}
public String getId(){
    return this.id;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public void setCategory(String category){
    this.category = category;
}
public String getCategory(){
    return this.category;
}
public void setImage(String image){
    this.image = image;
}
public String getImage(){
    return this.image;
}
public void setIndication(String indication){
    this.indication = indication;
}
public String getIndication(){
    return this.indication;
}
public void setPacked(boolean packed){
    this.packed = packed;
}
public boolean getPacked(){
    return this.packed;
}
public void setMed_id(String med_id){
    this.med_id = med_id;
}
public String getMed_id(){
    return this.med_id;
}
public void setDosage(int dosage){
    this.dosage = dosage;
}
public int getDosage(){
    return this.dosage;
}
}






   import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 public class Dosage
  {
private String id;

private String packed;

private List<Medicine> medicine;

public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
}
public String getId(){
    return this.id;
}
public void setPacked(String packed){
    this.packed = packed;
}
public String getPacked(){
    return this.packed;
}
public void setMedicine(List<Medicine> medicine){
    this.medicine = medicine;
}
public List<Medicine> getMedicine(){
    return this.medicine;
}
 }


 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 public class Band
  {
private String name;

private List<Dosage> dosage;

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public void setDosage(List<Dosage> dosage){
    this.dosage = dosage;
}
public List<Dosage> getDosage(){
    return this.dosage;
}
  }


 import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
   public class Timeline
  {
private DateTime Date;

private List<Band> band;

public void setDate(DateTime Date){
    this.Date = Date;
}
public DateTime getDate(){
    return this.Date;
}
public void setBand(List<Band> band){
    this.band = band;
}
public List<Band> getBand(){
    return this.band;
}
 }


 public class Root
 {
private boolean error;

private Timeline Timeline;

public void setError(boolean error){
    this.error = error;
}
public boolean getError(){
    return this.error;
}
public void setTimeline(Timeline Timeline){
    this.Timeline = Timeline;
}
public Timeline getTimeline(){
    return this.Timeline;
}
  }
```

...enjoy...

Comment: Hi Sanjana, I've almost done it with your help and others. Please tell me how do I get medicine values ? (Please check my edit 2)

Answer (score 0):

For first question:

> You can parse JSON without POJO classes but it is recommended to use
>   them and About you are stucking about generating them from the JSON
>   you can use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) I think
>   it is the best.

And for the second one:

Yest there are standards for JSON you can find them in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : First start with the inner most json object which I can see is "medicine"

Create a POJO class something like this

```
public class Medicine implements android.os.Parcelable {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

// Getter setter method for id
// Do it for all the JSON tags

}
```

Step 2 : Create a class for "medicineList" this will somewhat be like this

```
public class MedicineList implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("medicineList")
private List<Medicine > medicine;

// Getter setter can go here
}
```

In the similar fashion just move outside to your base tag in JSON response. This make things pretty easy for me to understand. I am not posting to the complete solution as thats your homework at EOD.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for Q1 -

Yes, you can parse above response using model classes by installing the DTO plugin in the Android Studio. The plugin will automatically create the POJO class for the response.